# How to pass instance of service from one module to another while registering

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I am new to NestJS and trying to pass `UserService` instance from `UserModule` to `AuthModule`, the idea is to make `AuthModule` flexible for the user service which implements particular methods enforced by interface and then `AuthModule` uses that to provide auth functionalities.

Here's the `AuthModule`

```ts
import { DynamicModule, Module } from "@nestjs/common";

import { AuthController } from "./controllers";
import { AuthService, UserService } from "./services";
import { IUserService } from "./services/interfaces";

@Module({})
export class AuthModule {
    static register(userService: IUserService): DynamicModule {
        return {
            module: AuthModule,
            controllers: [AuthController],
            providers: [
                AuthService,
                {
                    provide: UserService,
                    useValue: userService
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Here's how my `AppModule` looks like:

```ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UsersModule } from './users';
import { AuthModule } from './auth';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule.register(/* Here I would like to pass UserService instance */)
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`UserService`

```ts
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { IUserRepository, USER_REPOSITORY } from "../repositories";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(@Inject(USER_REPOSITORY) private repository: IUserRepository) {

    }
}
```

What I'm trying here is keeping `AuthModule` isolated so I don't have to import anything from `UserModule` but pass the `UserService` instance so I can communicate with database for users and also use of functionalities needed.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use UserService within the Auth module, you should specify it in your AuthService. For instance:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        private dbService: PrismaService,
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }
```

Then, you need to provide it within your AuthModule:

```
@Module({
    imports: [JwtModule.register({})],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, PrismaService, UserService],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

By following this, UserService will be injectable within AuthService, provided that UserService is exported by UsersModule.

However, note that, by doing so, you're importing UserService into AuthModule which you said you want to avoid. The idea behind modules in NestJS is to create well-encapsulated pieces of functionality that can be easily reused and maintained. If AuthModule relies on UserService, it's okay and even desirable to import UsersModule into AuthModule to make this dependency explicit.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that but what If I want to provide the AuthModule as a package and publish it on npm, that would require UserService to work with

Comment: You should also include the user.service.ts file in the package. However, you should learn how dependencies work within the package. This modular system is applicable in NestJS.

Comment: Hey @berat, can you please provide me a reference, I checked how dependency injection works but still not able to achieve this

Comment: @RohitKhatri I recommend reading this documentation. <https://docs.nestjs.com/providers>